# Angular 2 Reset Observable Timer

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service where I have a method getting called every 30 seconds automatically. I also have a button which will allow a user to reset the timer, preventing this method from getting called for another 30 seconds. How can I reset my timer so this method won't get called within that 30 seconds if the button is clicked?

COMPONENT

```
constructor(private service: Service) {
  this.service.initialize();
}

refreshTimer(): void {
  this.service.refreshTimer();
}
```

SERVICE

```
initialize(): void {
    timer(0, 30000).subscribe(() => this.refresh());
}

refreshTimer(): void {
  // Need help here
}
```

As you can see, my component calls initialize() from its constructor, which initializes the timer to run this.refresh() every 30 seconds. The idea is that my html will call refreshTimer() in the component, which will ultimately call refreshTimer() in the service to start the timer over. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `this.refresh()` do?

Comment: It just makes an api call to refresh data in a data table. I didn't think that was super relevant so I didn't include it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `switchMap` that unsubscribes the previous `timer` and subscribes to the new one that start all over again.

```
private reset$ = new Subject();

initialize(): void {
  this.reset$
    .pipe(
      startWith(void 0),
      switchMap(() => timer(0, 30000)),
    )
    .subscribe(() => this.refresh());
}

refreshTimer(): void {
  this.reset$.next(void 0);
}
```

The `startWith` operator is required to trigger creating the first `timer` on subscription.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I think this is close but it's triggering this.refresh() every time refreshTimer() is hit. How would we set up this so this.refresh() would only get called when the timer runs out?

Comment: You can use `interval(30000)` that won't make the initial emission

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass a count to the subscribe and only call refresh() when count is greater than 0. In this way, it will ignore the initial emission. subscribe((count) => {
        if (count > 0) {
          this.refresh();
        }

Comment: clear and perfect!

Answer (score 4):

You should unsubscribe then re-subscribe to the timer observable

```
t = timer(0, 30000);
sub: Subscription;

initialize(): void {
    this.sub = this.t.subscribe(() => this.refresh());
}

refreshTimer(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
    this.initialize();
}
```

or you can just have one method

```
t = timer(0, 30000);
sub: Subscription;

initTimer(): void {
    this.sub && this.sub.unsubscribe();
    this.sub = this.t.subscribe(() => this.refresh());
}
```

Comment: where is the `refresh()` method implementation?

Comment: `refresh()` is something you would like to do, when the timer is triggered, `this.sub = this.t.subscribe(() => console.log('job done'));` or as a method to the example above `refresh(): void { console.log('job done') }`