# Shared countdown timer observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a basic timer observable that I want to be shared across multiple subscribers.

```
time = 30;
timer$ = timer(0,1000).pipe(
    map(i => this.time - i),
    take(this.time + 1),
    finalize(() => console.log('DONE')),
    share()
);
```

I subscribe to the observable in both template and component, in the component to start the timer, and in the template to show the remaining time.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.runTimer();
}

runTimer() {
    this.timer$.subscribe();
}

{{ timer$ | async }}
```

This works, but only for the first time. If I call the runTimer() function again (e.g a button triggering that call), the timer starts again, but the change is not reflected in the template where I see `0` (probably because the previous timer finished).

What am I doing wrong?

I've created stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qc759v?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Reset Observable Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592260/angular-2-reset-observable-timer)

Comment: I don't get it. Does the timer$ unsub automatically because I have take(N)? I tried the solution from the accepted answer, but it is not working for me (see stackblitz). Do I really need an extra observable(Subject) to make it work?

Comment: It breaks my browser, goes into an infinite loop

Comment: You don't want a timer, you want a countdown, don't you?

Comment: This answer has a stopwatch that you can START, STOP, and RESET. If you use it instead of `timer`, you then have a robust way to reset the countdown. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676617/pause-an-interval-rxjs/64683558#64683558

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a while I found a solution.

This may not be the best solution but it works.

```
time = 5;

  timer$: Observable<number>;
  timerSub: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.startTimer();
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.timerSub && this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
    this.timer$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(i => {
        console.log(this.time - i);
        return this.time - i;
      }),
      take(this.time + 1),
      finalize(() => console.log("DONE")),
      share()
    );
    this.timerSub = this.timer$.subscribe();
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ibkbcu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the async, you can create a funcion that return the timer

```
  timer$(){
    return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(i => {
      console.log(this.time - i);
      return this.time - i;
    }),
    take(this.time + 1),
    finalize(() => console.log("DONE")),
    share()
  );
  }
  //define a new observable
  timerApp$

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.startTimer();
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.timerApp$=this.timer$();
  }
}
```

And use

```
{{timerApp$ |async}}
```

::glups:: it's the same answer than you found

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code `map(i => this.time - i)` I believe what you want is not a timer but rather a countdown. So I'll go for a demo with a countdown but if you really want a timer you should be able to work it out with a countdown code as very similar.

When working with observable, try hard not to:

- reassign the observable value
- use `subscribe`

Here's my proposal for a countdown:

TS side:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public countdownControl: FormControl = new FormControl(5);

  public startCountdown$$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  public countdown$: Observable<number> = this.startCountdown$$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.countdownControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.countdownControl.value))),
    switchMap(([_, countdownStartValueSeconds]) =>
      timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        map((_, index) => countdownStartValueSeconds - index),
        takeWhile(v => v >= 0)
      )
    )
  );
}
```

HTML side:

```
<h1>{{ countdown$ | async }}</h1>

Number of seconds for the countdown:
<input type="number" step="1" [formControl]="countdownControl">

<button (click)="startCountdown$$.next()">Start again</button>
```

Note that I'm assigning the observable value only once, never after and that there is no subscribe at all.

If the starting time is static you could simplify this code a bit by removing the `withLatestFrom` but I thought it'd be a good example to show how to have a variable we can update for the starting time.

Note: Of course (and thanks to the `switchMap` here), if a timer is running and you want to restart it just press the start button again.

**Here's a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gvsn66?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts**